# django many_to_many field deletion

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have two django models which I want to connect using a many to many relationship. See the below example:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
    aa = models.ManyToManyField(A, related_name='bs', blank=True, null=True)
```

What I am trying to figure out is what happens if I delete a record of A or of B? What I want to have happen is that the relations in the M2M are deleted, but the other object stays intact. Say a row in A is deleted, then the related rows in B should remain, only the connection through the m2m relationship should be deleted. I can't find it in the Django documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Here is the relevant part:

> If we delete a Publication, its Articles won’t be able to access it:
>
> `p1.delete()`
> `Publication.objects.all()`
> `<QuerySet [<Publication: Highlights for Children>, <Publication: Science News>, <Publication: Science Weekly>]>`
> `a1 = Article.objects.get(pk=1)`
> `a1.publications.all()`
> `<QuerySet []>`
>
> If we delete an Article, its Publications won’t be able to access it:
>
> `a2.delete()`
> `Article.objects.all()`
> `<QuerySet [<Article: Django lets you build Web apps easily>]>`
> `p2.article_set.all()`
> `<QuerySet []>`

In your case Django will create tables for the models **A** and **B** as well as an intermediary table, which is not reflected in the models. When you delete an object instance (a record) of the class **A**, the associated row in the table **A** will be deleted, as well as all associated rows in the intermediary table. The table **B** won't be affected.

Comment: But what if B instance is related to many A instances then we delete one of these A instances, what happens for the left instances related to B, can we always access them ?

Comment: @SidouMahmoud Since A and B are connected through a many-to-many (m:n) relationship, deleting one record from table A won't affect the relation of the other records. The answer is yes, if you have A1, A2 and A3 related to B1, and you delete A1, the relation between A2 and B1 and A3 and B1 remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

By making a m2m relation you're basically making another table with a foreign key to model A and another one to model B (Django does it for you).

By default `on_delete` is set to `models.CASCADE` which means if you delete a row in any of those models, the relation will be deleted too. (you can confirm it by deleting a row in your admin page which you'll see a message with list of all relationship that they will be deleted too)

You can make a table yourself to manage these things and connect that table to the model with `through=`. It's good way to manage m2m relations in a way you actually want.

Doc: [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Good answer, but I have one remark. Are you sure that `ManyToManyField` has `on_delete` parameter?

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood something. Do you mean the intermediary table connecting A with B will cascade per default?

Comment: @cezar not in manytomany field. in the table django makes for you which there will be 2 field one for each models involved in manytomany and for those fields (they are Foreignkey fields), `on_delete` is set to `models.CASCADE` and you can change it by making a model yourself and connect it with `through` instead of letting django make it for you with default settings.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, as per my second comment, I realized what you tried to  explain. Now it is completely clear.